# redux action type has optional payload property-typescript complains inside the reducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have the following redux action type in my react-ts project

```
type DataItem = {
 id: string
 country: string
 population: number
} 

type DataAction = {
 type: string,
 payload?: DataItem
}
```

I have optional `payload` property, because sometimes I don't pass a payload to the reducer. However, because of this, inside the reducer, typescript complains that `payload` may be `undefined`, although I don't use `payload` in the reducer unless I pass it in the action. Currently what I do I put ! after the payload `payload!` inside the reducer, but I wonder if there is another way to handle this issue, like maybe create two action types, one with a payload, and one without?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a conditional to check if the `payload` exists:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOBJYEC2UC8UDeBYAKCigEsATALigGdgAnEgOwHMBuQ4gYwHsBXR+iCq0GLdkShhuYXgBsEJboyqNeaAEYQ64gL7jCoSLARwAgp2CLGWXByiGIVAOQQAHnDRhZEJ+OJg4EFluODIAfip4RBR0XX0CADN+CysoOggyXk5oAApaBEcofgBrRm4Ad0YAGig4FKVIk3NLJQBKWwlqcpJgTgALKBy6lsYAOgd2-AkuOGpoF3dPbycqKeJ10gTBgEJhq1GAoJCydvTgXjprfNQ-Ddr6scPg0KgAeleoMvKavaUDwOeZFI1GM0VQaDsG3eUFGsPKfQKADctFAQHxPhAMvZuFAyDjusABk9jpCoDo7OSCDogA)

```ts
type DataAction = {
  type: 'example';
  payload?: DataItem;
};

function reduce (state: unknown, action: DataAction) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'example': {
      if (!action.payload) return state;
      action.payload // now, action.payload is DataItem
      // ...whatever you need to do with payload
    }
  }
}
```

Or use separate action types to handle the cases individually:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=28&ssc=2&pln=7&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOBJYEC2UC8UDeBYAKCigEsATALigGdgAnEgOwHMBuQ4gYwHsBXR+iCq0GLdkShhuYXgBsEJboyqNeaAEYQ64gL7jCoSLARwAgp2CLGAdRLAAFn2AAFOCFncyWXByiGIVADkjNwAtGBuHnBkgbr6BP7GiOaWSrYOru7c0d74Ev5BAO529uGR2THixBFZ0VTwiCjocYQG4NANZhZW3p0pVun2mVFeAD5JXak2JU7DnvEAZvzdSlB0EGS8nNAAFLQIAVD8ANYhhYwANFBwK8oT-UoAlD4S1MXAnPZQOzdTAHT+Z55YhcODUaDBMI1EaBKjAkHEdbAXh0Rg0RCoKognS+UHgqCBd6laEVWEvBHEX5WP4knIAejpUDOVypShp5RyJGoEyaaFxIIZUD+wsK9gOADctFAQHwmRANn5uFAyEqiZIOWR+TiJNqdEA)

```ts
type DataActionWithoutPaylod = {
  type: 'no-payload';
};

type DataActionWithPayload = {
  type: 'with-payload';
  payload: DataItem;
};

type DataAction = DataActionWithPayload | DataActionWithoutPaylod;

function reduce (state: unknown, action: DataAction) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'no-payload': {
      return state;
    }
    case 'with-payload': {
      action.payload // now, action.payload is DataItem
      // ...whatever you need to do with payload
    }
  }
}
```